# Allowing Javascript and CSS but not XSS

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, xss

We allow users to create rich content using TinyMCE and this includes Javascript and CSS.
However, when the content reaches server (Java), we want to filter out all XSS code or potentially malicious code, things like document.cookie, eval, etc, whether they are in CSS, inline JS, XSS Javascript crafted using string text (eg. document.write), etc. Everything else, eg. changing color on mouse over, set gradient on CSS, etc are fine.

We want to allow flexibility to our users but at the same time we want to ensure users are secured. We researched on libs like HTML Purifier, jSoup, but they do not seem smart enough to distinguish potentially malicious JS from safe one.
We are wondering if there is any way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you really do need JS for "rich content". CSS itself can get you very far nowadays, and dropping JS will make the whole thing cheaper to make.

Comment: things like on Mouse over an image display the enlarged picture, ie. preview, is quite popular. I doubt CSS alone can do that

Comment: Of course it can, a starting point is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajsyi . I'm sure you can do more with JS but running untrusted code on behalf of your website is a very problematic alternative.

Comment: that's true, flexibility to user is also important but worse case we just go with CSS, like you said. Or even worse, we only allow HTML.THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at google caja? It is a compiler for third party javascript so it can be safely embedded in another site:

https://developers.google.com/caja/

It sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: So far this is the best answer, I'm still researching it, since it requires server-side code deployment, but I wonder how Wordpress is doing it. I tried googling but no luck so far. If you or anyone can let me know, it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSoup for this job. JSoup has a XSS Cleaner Parser which can work on a whilelist Object (list of permitted tags).The jsoup whitelist sanitizer works by parsing the input HTML, and then iterating through the parse tree and only allowing known-safe tags and attributes (and values) through into the cleaned output. It does not use regular expressions, which are inappropriate for this task.
jsoup provides a range of Whitelist configurations to suit most requirements; they can be modified if necessary. Read this link for more details [http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer].

Comment: we actually tried it no luck. One example, it strips every 'onclick' when we actually want it to strip it only when onclick executes malicious code. Another example, style should be filtered ONLY when it contains malicious style='background:url("javascript:alert('XSS')")'. I guess we want the lib to be smart enough distinguishing malicious one from good one. JSoup does not have that capability.

Comment: I am afraid such a library does not exist to my knowledge. You may have to code the rules to make a whitelist and blacklist of JavaScript. You may make static rules, for example as used in Zozzle <https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CGcQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F152618%2Fusenixsec11b.pdf&ei=AXrFUpP8NK6XyQPcvIHADA&usg=AFQjCNGZB5kihAhiI0NpsCa2sIJN22_akg&sig2=iQErYLe7wYWQc_U19ysDTQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGQ‎>.